# Array.prototype.splice() Replace Editar Array

Tags: javascript, array

tengo este codigo:

```js
const tasksArray = []

const refresh = () => {
    const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks')
    const template = tasksArray.map(x => '<li>' + '<p>' + x + '</p>' + '<button>' + 'Delete' + '</button>' + '<button>' + 'Edit' + '</button>' + '</li>')
    tasks.innerHTML = template.join('')
    openModal()
        //taskEdit()
    taskDelete()
}

const form = document.getElementById('form-tasks')
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const task = document.getElementById('task')
    const tasksText = task.value
    task.value = ''
        //console.log(tasksText);
        //console.log(tasksArray);
    if (tasksText === '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea!')
    } else {
        tasksArray.push(tasksText)
        refresh()
    }
}

const taskDelete = () => {
    const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#tasks li button:nth-of-type(1)')
        //console.log(elementos);
    elementos.forEach((elemento, i) => {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
            elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento)
            tasksArray.splice(i, 1)
            refresh()
        })
    })
    if (tasksArray.length === 0) {
        const vacio = document.getElementById('tasks')
        vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>' + 'No hay tareas...' + '</h1>'
            //console.log(vacio)
    }
}

const openModal = () => {
    const modal = document.getElementById('modal')
    const editar = document.querySelectorAll('#tasks li button ~ button')
        //console.log(editar);
    editar.forEach(x => {
        x.onclick = () => {
            modal.style.display = 'block'
        }

        window.onclick = (e) => {
            if (e.target === modal) {
                modal.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    })
}

const formEdit = document.getElementById('form-edit')
formEdit.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks')
    const edit = document.getElementById('edit-task')
    edit.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        const textEdit = e.target.value
        console.log(textEdit);
    })

}

/* const taskEdit = () => {
    const formEdit = document.getElementById('form-edit')
    formEdit.onsubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const edit = document.getElementById('edit-task')
        edit.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            const textEdit = e.target.value
            console.log(textEdit);
            edit.value = ''
        })
    }
} */
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.content-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.content-right {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li>button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    display: inline;
}


/* Modal */

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left">
            <form id="form-tasks">
                <label>Add a Task</label>
                <input id="task" type="text" placeholder="Task..." />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <label>Search Task</label>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="tasks">
        <h1>No hay tareas...</h1>
        <!-- <li>comer <button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>jugar</li> -->
    </ol>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-edit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-task" />
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btn-modal" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

tengo un problema, en la parte de editar, me quede atorado,
puedo hacer que el modal muestre en consola los datos que escribo, pero no encuentro la forma de relacionarlo con el indice del array, para pode rmodificar el elemento, estuve investigando y la solocuion es con array splice: ya hice un ejercicio para entender como funciona

mi aplicacion es una lista de tareas, ya he podido crear tareas y borrarlas,
mi buscador no funciona, porque aun no tiene codigo para que funcione, ahora estoy algo atorado en esta funcion de editar
quiero actualizar un elemento de mi arreglo de tareas,
pero no se como implementarlo, agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a mejorar en tu código:

- Accede a cada elemento de lista por su índice, que debe ser el mismo del arreglo.
- Define primero todas las variables y funciones necesarias; si vas a usar variables en más de una función, entonces deben estar en contexto global. Probablemente se me escapó alguna, ya te tocará revisar. La ventaja es que las defines solo una vez y **la única que debe definirse cada que se va a usar es donde obtienes todos los LI**.
- Crea el contenido de cada elemento de lista usando [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para evitar concatenaciones y facilitar la lectura.
- Usa clases para los botones editar y borrar, de forma que no tengas que asignar eventos directamente, en este caso, es mejor delegar, tal como haces para cerrar la ventana modal.
- Crea una función para cada tarea específica; en editar y borrar, va a ser necesario obtener el índice del elemento de la lista para poder asociarlo con el del arreglo.
- En lugar de volver a crear todo el contenido de la lista con cada acción:

  - Al agregar una tarea, solo concatena el nuevo contenido
  - Al editar, solo actualiza el elemento
  - Al eliminar, solo remueve el elemento

Cuando defines variables y funciones primero, estás creando la lógica del *script* y, lo que viene después es cómo ejecutarlo:

- Asignas evento *submit* a los formularios, ejecutando la función que corresponda
- Asignas evento *click* a la lista (`#tasks`), donde analizas si el clic fue en un botón y, de ser el caso, ejecutar la función para editar o borrar, enviando el evento

Esta propuesta es muy diferente a tu código original, teniendo en cuenta que solo preguntaste cómo hacer para editar, sin embargo, considero te hará las cosas más fáciles, especialmente sabiendo que planeas crear un buscador.

Revisa los comentarios en el código y no dudes en preguntar si hay algo que no entiendes.

```js
const tasksArray = []
const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
const form = document.getElementById('form-tasks');
const formEdit = document.getElementById('form-edit');

// Insertar o actualizar tarea
const redraw = (task, index) => {
    // Crear HTML con plantillas de texto
    const template = `<li>
      <p>${task}</p>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
      </li>`;
    if(index < 0) {
        // Agregar tarea
        tasks.innerHTML += template;
        tasksArray.push(task);
    } else {
        // Actualizar tarea
        const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
        if(items && items[index]) {
            // Solo si realmente existe
            // OuterHTML remplaza todo el elemento
            items[index].outerHTML = template;
            tasksArray[index] = task;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('vacio').innerHTML = '';
};
// Función para obtener índice de elemento
const taskFind = (item) => {
    const items = tasks.querySelectorAll('li');
    // Valor si no se encuentra el elemento
    let index = -1;
    // Recorrer para buscar
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i] == item) {
            // Elemento encontrado, actualizar índice y salir del ciclo
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Devolver índice o -1
    return index;
};
// Función para borrar, recibe evento
const taskDelete = (e) => {
    // e.target es el botón
    // .closest('li') selecciona el contenedor al que pertenece el botón
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    // Agregar confirmación
    if(index >= 0 && confirm('¿Borrar tarea?')) {
        // Eliminar
        e.target.closest('li').remove();
        tasksArray.splice(index, 1);
        if (tasksArray.length == 0) {
            const vacio = document.getElementById('tasks');
            vacio.innerHTML = '<h1>No hay tareas...</h1>';
        }
    }
};
// Función para editar, recibe evento
const taskEdit = (e) => {
    index = taskFind(e.target.closest('li'));
    if(index >= 0) {
        // Abrir modal enviando índice de elemento a editar
        openModal(index);
    }
};

// Abrir modal, recibe índice del elemento
const openModal = (index) => {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    // Asignar índice a dataset de formulario, para saber cuál se está editando
    formEdit.dataset.index = index;
    // Asignar valor a campo de formulario
    document.querySelector('#edit-task').value = tasksArray[index];
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const task = document.getElementById('task')
    const tasksText = task.value
    task.value = ''
    if (tasksText === '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea!')
    } else {
        // Insertar elemento en arreglo y mostrar
        redraw(tasksText, -1);
    }
});

formEdit.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const edit = document.getElementById('edit-task');
    const value = edit.value;
    if(value == '') {
        alert('Escribe una tarea');
    } else {
        // Cerrar modal
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        // Actualizar valor, en dataset está el índice del elemento
        redraw(value, parseInt(formEdit.dataset.index));
    }
});
// Delegar clics para activar botones
tasks.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const item = e.target;
    // Buscar botón por clase
    if(item.classList.contains('delete')) {
        taskDelete(e);
    } else if(item.classList.contains('edit')) {
        taskEdit(e);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.content-left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.content-right {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li>button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    display: inline;
}


/* Modal */

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-left">
            <form id="form-tasks">
                <label>Add a Task</label>
                <input id="task" type="text" placeholder="Task..." />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <label>Search Task</label>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol id="tasks">
    </ol>
    <div id="vacio"><h1>No hay tareas...</h1></div>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-edit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-task" />
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btn-modal" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Nota:** Aunque funciona `elemento.onEVENTO`, es recomendable usar [`elemento.addEventListener('EVENTO', funcion)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo de comentar el codigo y la explicación, me ayudo bastante a comprenderlo. Gracias!

Comment: una pregunta, como podria llamar el indice de el elemento que quiero buscar?, en el ejemplo que pusiste lo llamaste con la funcion taskFind(), pero cuando intento pasarle como parametro un string que seria lo que escribo en el buscador, me devuelve : -1

Comment: Debes crear una función aparte, donde recorres el arreglo para buscar coincidencias, teniendo en cuenta que puedes obtener cero, una o más y, con los índices obtenidos, muestras solo los que coinciden. Habría que ver si usas el atributo display para mostrar / ocultar o asignas una clase para resaltar. De cualquier forma, creo que es buena idea hacerlo en otra pregunta.

Comment: gracias, intentare con reduce, antes de formular otra pregunta